# How to use QCustomPlot in plot real time

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

`QCustomPlot` has `setData` function that accepts const variable.
Is there a way to `QCustomPlot` can be use to plot dynamically?
`QCustomPlot` `setData` function accepts constant vectors, but I have to change the values in this vector dynamically.

```
const QVector<double> yval(cl);
const QVector<int> xval(cl);


for (int j = 0; j<cl; j++)
    yval[j] = ui->tableView->model()->data(ui->tableView->model()->index(5, j)).toDouble();
for (int j = 0; j<cl; j++)
{
    xval[j] = j;
}
ui->widget->graph()->setData(xval, yval);
```

Comment: You can call 'setdata' each time, when your data is changed.

Comment: I fixed the indentation of the code and ended your question with a ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [QCPGraph::data()](http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPGraph.html#a2f58436df4f86a2792b776a21642b3d9). The documentation of QCustomPlot sates that :

> Returns a pointer to the internal data storage of type QCPDataMap. You
>   may use it to directly manipulate the data, which may be more
>   convenient and faster than using the regular setData or addData
>   methods, in certain situations.

You can manipulate data in QCustomPlot like :

```
for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    plot->graph()->data()[i] = y[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

You call `setData()` with your new data, then `customPlot()->replot()`

I use it within a 50ms timer and it works very well.

Comment: The above code is not working because the setData() function takes setData(const double Vector key , const double Vector value); I was giving int vector values. and QT was complaining about corresponding function not found and was pointing out rightly